# Qt Save screenshot - naming problems

Tags: c++, qt

I want to save the screenshot of my application to the desktop. The problem is, it saves but if I take another screenshot it replaces the old image. How can I tell Qt to call it Wishlist 1, Wishlist 2 etc.?

```
QString filepath = QDir::toNativeSeparators( QDir::homePath() + "/Desktop/Wishlist.png"  );
    if( grab().save( filepath, "png" ) )
        statusBar()->showMessage( tr("Saved file to Desktop.") );
    else
        statusBar()->showMessage( tr("Error saving file.") );
```

After I close and start the program again, it should be able to go on. E.g. *Wishlist 1*, *Wishlist 2* then restart and then it should name the next screenshot *Wishlist 3*.

Comment: to the guy who downvoted, please tell me whats wrong so I can improve it.

Comment: QDir::homePath() + "/Desktop/Wishlist" + someInt + ".png"; someInt++

Comment: I think you need to show up some effort in solving this task, i.e. it is not visible that you even tried so far. For example read existing file names and generate new one (unique). P.S. I am not the down voter, btw.

Comment: @ChristianRapp well then I would have to store this integer in some file, load it and read it after restart... isn't there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Sure there is, but you asked how to avoid overriding the last file. Ok ok, do as vahancho told you. Have a look at QDir::entryInfoList || QDir::entryList. From there its just a matter of string parsing/sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a function for resolving the filename. the following snippet is not safe (what if no get's too large) and for the no == 0 you need a special case.

```
int no = 0;
while( true ){
    QString path = filename + "." + QString::number( no ) + "." + extention;
    QFileInfo fileInfo( path );
    if( !fileInfo.exists() )
        return path;
    no++
}
```